# Cropping problem with Nixon Coolpix P510

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, point-and-shoot, coolpix

Using Nikon Coolpix P510 camera.  When I try to crop an image I receive a message "image cannot be modified"  Help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post the image?

Comment: Is there any chance you've set image protection on for that image?

Answer (score 1):

It likely has to do with the image size that is selected.  If you use those for 3:2, 16:9, or 1:1, most of the in-camera editing functions are not available.  See manual page on "Picture Editing Functions."  There is a footnote about the restrictions.